# Check if an option is clicked

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to check if an option is clicked (without submitting the form) using jquery.
JQuery will then run a function to update information on the page via AJAX depending on which item is clicked.

My code.

PHP/HMTL

```
<select name="year_ordered" id="year_ordered">
 <option>2020</option>
 <option>2019</option>
 <option>2018</option>
</select>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.year_ordered option').each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':selected')) { 
                alert(this.value)
            }
        });
    });
```

I can't get any code to run.

Comment: you have to change `$('.year_ordered option')` by `$('#year_ordered option')` because the `.` selector selects a class and `#`selects an id and you have an id here in your html `id="year_ordered"`, not a class.

Comment: Your js code run only on page load. You need to attach `change` event to `$('#year_ordered')`. See this doc: https://api.jquery.com/change/